# How is X-ray capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalize X in x-ray?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/capitalize-x-in-x-ray)

I see in the OED and on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray#cite_note-1) that 'X-ray' can be both 'x-ray' and 'X-ray'; is there a preferred version for American English?

Comment: It is indeed, I didn't see that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just Googling "x-ray" I see about equal usage of all three capitalization modes (X-Ray, X-ray, and x-ray).  Wikipedia prefers "X-ray," as does [this Stanford page on the TIP Style Guide](http://www2.slac.stanford.edu/tip/rulesTIP.html#Spelling), but those are just data points.